# Spring Boot GET request returning 400 for images

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have my post request for uploading image as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = BASE_PATH)
public ResponseEntity<?> createFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest servletRequest){

    URI localUri = null;
    try{
        imageService.createImage(file);
        final URI localhostUri = new URI(servletRequest.getRequestURL().toString() + "/")
                                        .resolve(file.getOriginalFilename() + "/raw");

        localUri = localhostUri;

    }catch (IOException e){
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                        .body("Could not upload " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "=>" + e.getMessage());
    }catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.created(localUri)
            .body("Successfully Uploaded " + file.getOriginalFilename());
}
```

And following is the GET method for fetching an image at a time:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = BASE_PATH + "/" + FILENAME + "/raw")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> oneRawImage(@PathVariable String filename){

    try{
        Resource file = imageService.findOneImage(filename);
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentLength(file.contentLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(file.getInputStream()));
    }catch (IOException e){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
                            .body("Couldn't Find" + filename + "=>" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

When i do a POST, i get a proper response stating the file is uploaded(I am not sure if it is, because the return request is out of the try block. Following is the response I get:

```
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /images HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 69927
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------
b5f1ef58e19bbb8d
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 
< HTTP/1.1 201 
< Location: http://localhost:8080/images/image2.jpg/raw
< Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 32
< Date: Wed, 14 Jun 2017 18:24:06 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Successfully Uploaded image2.jpg
```

But when i try to do a GET request to get the image i posted, i receive the following error:

```
Couldn't Findimage2.jpg=>ServletContext resource [/fileupload-dir/image2.jpg] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
```

I tried debugging in multiple ways, but was not successful. Any help from springers will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: is `/fileupload-dir/` mapped correctly? I cannot tell from the code provided - Your method seems to be mapped to `../raw`

Comment: @ochi this is interesting, in the findOneImage Service method, I actually missed a colon at resourceLoader.getResource("file:" + UPLOAD_ROOT + "/" + filename). I didnt exactly understand the use of the ':' but thats where the problem was.

Comment: Your question title is misleading... the title says that you get a 404 (resource not found) but really you are getting a 400 (bad request) - now we know why...

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.. I am changing it @ochi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i realized the issue was a pretty menial one. The service method being called:

```
public Resource findOneImage(String filename){
    return resourceLoader.getResource("file:" + UPLOAD_ROOT + "/" + filename);
}
```

The colon was missing in the 'file'. Hence resourceLoader was not getting resolved to a correct url.